# Required import libraries

Tags: java, android, import

I'm starting an Android program that needs to run a shell script, using as a starting point the code snippet below found here:

[How can we execute a shell script file from my Android Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957385/how-can-we-execute-a-shell-script-file-from-my-android-application)

My problem is getting it to compile. I'm getting "cannot find symbol" errors for InputStreamReader and others, surely because I'm missing a required import.

This happens all the time. Are there standard libs I should be importing? What's needed for this code snippet?

```
void execCommandLine()
    {
       //*********************** 
        try
        {
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = rt.exec("ls -all");

        proc = rt.exec("sh /data/shTest.sh");
        InputStream is = proc.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;

   while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
     System.out.println(line);
   }
       } catch (Throwable t)
      {
        t.printStackTrace();
      }


Edit: I got my compile by adding:
import java.io.InputStream;   
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
```

Comment: mport java.io.InputStream;   
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

Answer (score 0):

hint... Control-Shift-O (Command-Shift-O on macos) will take care of your imports in eclipse I'm of course assuming you're using eclipse if you're doing android.  That being said, eclipse should be suggesting imports for you as you go along.

Try typing "InputSt" and hitting Control-Space, and you'll see what i mean.

Comment: Does Stack hate vi users? Holy moly, banned after 5 questions. I don't know enough java to answers questions yet!!

Comment: nothing wrong with vi, except that eclipse does the mundane little things for me, like adding imports without having to scroll all the way to the top of the file, generating getters and setters, creating overriden method shells for me, constructors, etc.... (all things netbeans, intellij, etc... can do too).  I use VI for quick file edits, but for coding, no way.

Comment: Screw vi and eclipse too. I'm talking about being banned from asking questions after asking a total of 5  or 6 in the course of learning java over three months! This is the most bizarre crap I've ever seen. Vampire my rear.